# perl use hash to read a file

Tags: windows, perl, csv, hash

I am trying to write a function in Perl which takes a hash and a file name as input.

Basically my hash is like this eg datahash is the name of the hash then

```
datahash(Attr1) = 1
datahash(Attr2) = 5
datahash(Attr3) = 4
datahash(Attr4) = 6
```

My file is a csv with Attr1,Attr2.. as the column names in the csv and the valuess of the hash are the column numbers in the same file.

My function needs to extract data from the file based on the hash keys and values. Any clues or ideas ? It needs to match the column name of the file to the hash, find out the column number and then extract the values of the column numbers. Several columns need to be extracted.

Below is the code I have: (Don't bother about the multiple prints I can put a loop)

```
my %dataHash = %{$_[0]};
my $fileName = $_[1];   
my @keys = keys %dataHash;
my @values = values %dataHash;
open my $info, $file;
while( my $line = <$info>)  
{
            my @arrdata = split(/,/, $line);
            print @arrdata[values[0]];
            print @arrdata[values[1]];
            print @arrdata[values[2]];
            print @arrdata[values[3]];
            print @arrdata[values[4]];
            print @arrdata[values[5]];          
    }
```

Sample file  :

```
attr1,abc,def,ghi,attr3,attr2,attr4,attr5,attr6
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19
11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19
11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19
```

SO the hash has the column names and column numbers I need to extract and the file is like this.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `@keys`? Seems like you do not use it in the loop..

Comment: Just extracted for now. most of the manipulation needs to be done by values only

Comment: Still unclear what you want to achieve. Please offer a sample input file and your expected output of that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text%3a%3aCSV)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;

my @rows;
my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { binary => 1 } )
    or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag ();

my $fh = \*DATA; # Open a fh instead

my $header = $csv->getline( $fh );

while ( my $row = $csv->getline( $fh ) ) {
    my %hash;
    @hash{@$header} = @$row;
    push @rows, \%hash;
}
$csv->eof or $csv->error_diag();
close $fh;

use Data::Dump;
dd \@rows;

__DATA__
attr1,abc,def,ghi,attr3,attr2,attr4,attr5,attr6
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19
11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19
11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19
```

Outputs:

```
[
  {
    abc   => 2,
    attr1 => 1,
    attr2 => 6,
    attr3 => 5,
    attr4 => 7,
    attr5 => 8,
    attr6 => 9,
    def   => 3,
    ghi   => 4,
  },
  {
    abc   => 12,
    attr1 => 11,
    attr2 => 16,
    attr3 => 15,
    attr4 => 17,
    attr5 => 18,
    attr6 => 19,
    def   => 13,
    ghi   => 14,
  },
  {
    abc   => 12,
    attr1 => 11,
    attr2 => 16,
    attr3 => 15,
    attr4 => 17,
    attr5 => 18,
    attr6 => 19,
    def   => 13,
    ghi   => 14,
  },
  {
    abc   => 12,
    attr1 => 11,
    attr2 => 16,
    attr3 => 15,
    attr4 => 17,
    attr5 => 18,
    attr6 => 19,
    def   => 13,
    ghi   => 14,
  },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

To get you started, you could try the following:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my %dataHash;
$dataHash{Attr1} = 1;
$dataHash{Attr2} = 5;
$dataHash{Attr3} = 4;
$dataHash{Attr4} = 6;

my $fileName = 'file.csv';

my @keys = keys %dataHash;
my @values = map {$_-1} values %dataHash;

open (my $info, "<", $fileName);

while( my $line = <$info>)  
{
   chomp $line;
   my @arrdata = split(/,/, $line);
   print "@arrdata[@values]\n";
}

close($info);
```

Comment: You should never parse CSV files by hand. Use CPAN modules (e.g. Text::CSV)

Comment: @DVK Agree, but I was not trying to give a complete solution.